# SQL Server / Link Server SOTAMAS90?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Can anyone tell me how to create a link server in SQL Server 2005 with SOTAMAS90?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that SOTAMAS90 is the Netbios name of the server.

I'd open up SQL Server Management Studio, expand server objects, linked servers, and then right-click NEW.

try to figure out if the machine name is still supposed to be SOTAMAS90.

Btw, MAS90 is a ERP program, right?

What's SOTA stand for?